# An Expedient Method for Perfectly Fitting an Image to a Pspicture

Tags: graphics, xetex, pstricks, pspicture, frame

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=4pt](-5,-5)(5,12)% 
\rput(0,3.5){\includegraphics[width=.86\linewidth,height=1.49\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The output is what I want; however, the method I used to obtain it was *trial and error*. More specifically, I centered the image into the `pspicture` at `(0,3.5)` and then tried various values until I arrived at `width=.86\linewidth` and `height=1.49\linewidth` which seems to produce what I want.

QUESTION: Is there a more expedient approach that I may use that does not involve trial and error to automatically fit perfectly, an image within a `pspicture` such as the one I have outlined?

I compile the code with `xelatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `lualatex`. Put the origin into the lower left!

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}% For opacity and lualatex
\DocumentMetadata{}                     % For opacity and lualatex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
        \psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=4pt,dimen=inner](-5,-5)(5,12)% 
        \rput[lb](-5,-5){\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=17cm]{example-image-a}}
        \psframe*[opacity=0.2,linecolor=red](-5,-5)(5,12)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just compute the values with TeX?

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=4pt](-5,-5)(5,12)% 
\rput(0,3.5){\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr10cm-8pt\relax,height=\dimexpr17cm-8pt\relax]{example-image-a}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Where `10cm` and `17cm` is computed by subtracting the corresponding coordinates, and `8pt` is double the `linewidth` value. (you could also write `4pt*2`)