# Replacing Title Color with Image Background

Tags: graphics, pstricks, overlays, includegraphics, pspicture

This is a follow-up question to [An Expedient Method for Perfectly Fitting an Image to a Pspicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661295/an-expedient-method-for-perfectly-fitting-an-image-to-a-pspicture)

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

% Overlay Title
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \Huge
  \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{white}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.45pt}{\usebox1}}
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=4pt](-5,-5)(5,12)% 
\rput(0,3.5){\includegraphics[width=.87\linewidth,height=1.49\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{pspicture}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.09,-5.09)(5.09,12.09)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{yellow!65!red}%
\psframe[fillcolor=yellow!65!red,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=4pt](-5.09,-5.09)(5.09,12.09)% 

% TITLE 
\rput(0,6.25){\vstretch{1.25}{\mytitle{CUT-OUT TITLE}}}
\rput(0,5){\vstretch{1.25}{\mytitle{AND PLACE}}}
\rput(0,3.75){\vstretch{1.25}{\mytitle{OVER IMAGE}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces the two pages of output

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: How may I, effectively, cut out the three-lined *white portion* of the title on the page 1 `pspicture` and then overlay that `pspicture` on the page 1 image---so that what appears is the page 2 `pspicture` whose title is no longer white, but contains the page 1 image for a background?
*Note:* The original black overlay produced by `\mytitle` will remain visible on the revised `pspicture`.

Comment: So, the picture will be visible through the letters? Would a `tikz` solution be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works only with `latex->dvips->ps2dpf`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-char}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
\begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt]{\rput(0,3.5){\RM\shortstack{Cut-out title\\line 2\\line 3}}}%
\rput[lb](-5,-5){\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=17cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{pscharclip}
%\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=4pt,dimen=inner](-5,-5)(5,12)% 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get a warning, that I should use `pst-text` instead of `pst-char`, however.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter, `pst-char`  automatically loads `pst-text`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `\pscharclip` that comes with the `pst-text` package:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian,pst-text}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

% Overlay Title
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{% #1 = title
    \parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\Huge\textbf{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\mytitleA}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \Huge\textbf{#1}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.09,-5.09)(5.09,12.09)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{yellow!65!red}%
\psframe[fillcolor=yellow!65!red,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=4pt](-5.09,-5.09)(5.09,12.09)% 

% TITLE 
\newdimen{\shiftedY}
\pssetlength{\shiftedY}{5cm}
\psaddtolength{\shiftedY}{-1.45pt}

\rput(0,\shiftedY){\vstretch{1.25}{\mytitle{CUT-OUT TITLE \\ AND PLACE \\ OVER IMAGE}}}

\pscharclip[linewidth=0pt,linestyle=none]{
    \rput(0,5){\vstretch{1.25}{\mytitle{CUT-OUT TITLE \\ AND PLACE \\ OVER IMAGE}}}
}
    \rput(0,3.5){\includegraphics[width=.87\linewidth,height=1.49\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\endpscharclip

\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using [this nice suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660648/47927) as a starting point, you can do the following using Ti*k*Z. I tried to recreate your example as closely as possible, but it still seems to be different especially regarding the font size. I hope the main idea is clear anyways. You should use PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile this.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytitle, color=transparent!0]
    
        % create fading from title
        \node[text width=\linewidth, align=center, font=\bfseries\Huge, yscale=1.25, transform shape] at (current page.center) {#2};
        
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    
        % orange background
        \fill[yellow!65!red, draw=black, line width=8pt] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    
        % text title shadow
        \fill[path fading=mytitle, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        
        % text title cut out
        \fill[path fading=mytitle, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
            \includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{#1}
        };}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\mytitle{background}{CUT-OUT TITLE \\ AND PLACE \\ OVER IMAGE}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, regarding the `\includegraphics` command, when I replace `{#1}` with `example-image-a` the code works fine; however, if I replace `{#1}` with an actual imgae (e.g., a png image)---the image is no longer in the background underneath the title, but is imposed *over* the orange picture. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Also, the actual document I am working on produces a `pspicture` with various `psvectorian` images---so, I don't think I would be able to revise it into a `tikz` picture. Do you know of a way that your code could be modified into a `pspicture`? Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians I cannot reproduce the problem you are having. You may need to compile twice to get the positioning right. I need to check whether this is also possible using a `pspicture`.

Comment: @mlchristians I think you need to take care how to compile. PSTricks does not work with PDFLaTeX, while the Ti*k*Z solution requires PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I updated my answer to include a solution using PSTricks.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer; incidentally, I was not compiling with `pdflatex`.